# Is it possible to join two tables into one single table , both tables have the same column names ...?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to join two tables in mysql  into one single table , both tables have the same column names ...?

table a has

```
id name state
1  jose  up
2  sam   mp
3  jack  tn
```

table b is

```
id name state 
4  ken  ker
5  sk   wb
```

is it possible to join both like:

```
id name state
1  jose  up
2  sam   mp
3  jack  tn 
4  ken   ker
5  sk    wb
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Use UNION

Comment: The resulting output of your query is **UNION** and not **JOIN**

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
  id,name,state
from
  tbla
UNION ALL
SELECT
  id,name,state
from
  tblb
```

If you want the exact duplicates to be excluded from the output. Use `UNION`

```
SELECT
   id,name,state
from
   tbla
UNION
SELECT
   id,name,state
from
   tblb
```

Reference:

- [13.2.8.4 UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: WHAT IF I HAVE 5,6 TABLES?

Comment: @user3304713 : You can still use a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` if you have 5 or 6 tables. You just continue adding `UNION` clauses

Answer (score 0):

The requirement you are describing is a `union all` query, not a `join`:

```
SELECT id, name, state
FROM   table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, state
FROM   table_b
```

Comment: WHAT IF I HAVE 5,6 TABLES?

Comment: Then you add 5,6 `union all`s: `select id, name, state from tablea union all select id, name, state from tableb union all select id, name, state from tablec...`